# PHP- cannot change max_execution_time in xampp

Tags: php, time, web-crawler

I've tried everything to change the `max_execution_time` of a php crawler script so that it can run an infinite amount of time.

I have changed the php.ini file setting `max_execution_time` to `0` or `100000000` but with no change

I've also tried setting it from the php script itself by using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

All php scripts throw the same error `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 3000 seconds exceeded`, what could I be missing and how can I make sure there is no max execution time limit?

**php script**

```
<?php
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 123456);
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/*code which scrapes websites*/

?>
```

**phpinfo()**

```
max_execution_time  0   0
max_input_time     -1   -1
```

Comment: Did you restart apache and PHP after setting a different max_execution_time on php.ini? :)

Comment: I think you should first optimize your script. 3000 Seconds is a long time for a php file. Otherwise you should run your script over the command line.

Comment: Sorry I was watching football, I forgot about this when no1 answered it.

Comment: @Stony it's hard to optimize a php crawler.

Comment: Yes ok you win :D but when you make a phpinfo(); which value is set for the max_execution_time? And is really the correct php.ini file loaded? And a really common mistake... search for a second entry in your php.ini file ;)

Comment: @Stony i've spent a lot of time on this, on phpinfo() max_execution_time is 0 (infinite)

Comment: @mk_89: PHP is not really the best language to build a crawler so i don't know if there is a hard limit in php. Perhaps the max_input_time parameter make problems. This should be 0, too.

Comment: @Stony no I've set max_input_time to -1 (infinite), I think php is ok for a web crawler, after all php is the language of the web.

Comment: Did you try set_time_limit()? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @Mahn I'll give that a shot and let it run for a while

Comment: You'll have to post code then.

Comment: What if you change the `php.ini` setting to `max_execution_time = 4`? What error does it display then?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff it would be the same as setting it to 0, trust me i've tried all possibilities

Comment: So does it say `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 4 seconds exceeded`??

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff no actually no matter value I change it whether it be in the php.ini file or from the actual php script it always says `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 3000 seconds`

Comment: That means that it isn't applying whatever value you are putting in. Have you tried [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)?

Comment: What does this give you: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time')); var_dump(ini_get('max_input_time'))`. Also a full output of `phpinfo()` would help.

Comment: post ur script block first... Have u tried all those which are suggested...

Comment: @Boopa yesterday i've tried all suggestions

Comment: Could it be the bug referenced in this SO post?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506538/php-max-execution-time-ignored-no-safe-mode-no-shared-host-just-localhost-win

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't let your crawler run under apache, it's better to run it stand-alone via cli as part of a [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) setup.

That way it won't hog your web server and it can run as long as you want. You can find many bindings for Gearman that you can use, including PHP of course.

Comment: I'll give this a shot if all ends badly, right now im going to try running the php file in command prompt as it could be a browser issue, what really drives me nuts is when something that should work doesn't

Answer (score 4):

Try turning off **safe mode** in php and then try the below code

```
if( !ini_get('safe_mode') ){ 
    set_time_limit(0); //this won't work if safe_mode is enabled.
}
```

This should allow you to run the script for infinite time.

In Apache you can change maximum execution time by .htaccess with this line

```
php_value max_execution_time 200
```

[set_time_limit() php manual ref.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: @mk_89 did you turn off safe mode of php? if you did try reinstalling your xampp

Comment: I did turn it off, maybe I will reinstall it

Comment: unfortunately it did not make a difference

Answer (score 2):

use

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

at the top of the script

Answer (score 0):

In WAMP there is three PHP.ini files so you might find 3 in xampp also, so just search for it with find and replace `max_execution_time` to what you are setting. But you must keep something small not too large as for speedy the app you running.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting `ignore_user_abort(TRUE);` in your script as it might be the browser timing out rather than the script.

From the php.net manual

```
<?php
// Ignore user aborts and allow the script
// to run forever
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

See here for more info

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, and this is a CLI run script [maybe read this](http://www.flipflops.org/2008/07/27/xampp-and-the-php-cli/).

Answer (score 0):

check `phpinfo()` from a temp script and search for `max_execution_time`. make sure that it has same value what you are setting. default should be 30 seconds. try to change it to a couple of different values and restart apache then check the value in `phpinfo()` to confirm.

if when you change the value it is reflected properly in the `phpinfo()` it means that there is some code in your script which is changing this value. search for two things in your code:

1. search your code for `ini_set()` and check if it is change `max_execution_time`
2. search for `set_time_limit()`

these functions can change maximum time limit of execution from script. otherwise you should check `.htaccess` from where this value may be set. but this will effect `phpinfo()` also.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following in the [xampp documentation](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#phpini). Maybe you are trying to edit the wrong php.ini file?

> Why have changes in my php.ini no effect?
>
> Since XAMPP 1.7.1 the "php.ini" is only in the directory "\xampp\php". Till XAMPP 1.7.0 is was in the directory "\xampp\apache\bin".
>
> If a change in the "php.ini" have no effect, it's possible PHP is still using an other one. You can verify this with phpinfo(). Go to the URI localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php and search for "Loaded Configuration File". This value shows you the "php.ini" PHP is really using.
>
> Info:
> After changing the "php.ini" you have to restart Apache, thus Apache/PHP can read the new settings.

Comment: I have check phpinfo() before and the changes I've made have been set

Comment: Okay, i have found another question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103952/max-value-of-max-input-time) which mentions max_input_time. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is just setting the `max_execution_time` to whatever inside your page. 
you can't change this using ini_set. you can change the `memory_limit` only.

[see more details here...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)
from the php official site.

if you want them to be  changed, change in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both of these in you php.ini ( and check if that's the right php.ini by finding the location in `phpinfo();` output! )

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = 0
```

And after that check if some php file is not overwriting those variables locally.

Answer (score 0):

open php.ini notepad file and search or find `upload_max_filesize = 1000M` and you should change on `Post_max_filesize = 1000M` then restart your xampp and refresh the local phpmyadmin..