# PHP sleep function doesn't work

Tags: php, php-5.3

this one :

> sleep(30);
>   echo'test';
>   die();

works on local (MAMP) but not on my server (Ubuntu, Apache..), I tried to add `set_time_limit(300);` It is appears good on `phpinfo` at `max_execution_time = 300` but still doesn't work. I still get an error page on browser (Firefox "The connection was reset").

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

**max_execution_time** By default is already 30. If php script is longer then 30, then apache will stop this script. So at first of all, you need make bigger **max_execution_time**.

If your script is longer then 300, then you should use unlimited time for this script.
Unlimited execution you can set with **set_time_limit(0);**

You can read this theard too.

[Execution time problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284731/php-cannot-change-max-execution-time-in-xampp)

Comment: My script time 30 seconds and the executime time is 5 minutes (and its appair as it in phpinfo), i tried set_time_limit(0); still dont work.

Comment: Look at log file. See where and why script stops working. There you should find answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try after restarting your Apache server in Ubuntu.