# max_execution_time not working on only 1 script

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set the max_execution_time on 1200 in .htaccess for a script i need te be executed.
I works fine on 99% of my scripts; but 1 is refusing to run for longer than a few second.
This is a script that does multiple sql actions but a similar script that only does the first insert /add (with a lot of similar codes) does work.

Added: I was on shared hosting, then it worked fine but after switching to a prive "container" it does not work anymore.
On the shared hosting i had to set the longer time-out in the script itself, after upgrading the longer time-out is in my htaccess.

could it be that in some strange way the .htaccess does not apply/work on my script or is there an mysql error? My error log says nothing. The e-mail at the end of the script is being send.

The php version is: 5.3.28-1.

The script:

```
    <?php require_once('../../includes/connect.php');
require_once('../../includes/functions.php');

mysql_select_db($database, $databaseConnect);

// get product feed options  - maybe needed
$getFeedOptions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliSt_config WHERE name = 'feedOptions' LIMIT 1");
$theFeedOptions = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFeedOptions);
$feedOpts = explode(':',$theFeedOptions['value']);

if (isset($_GET['fd_refresh'])) {


$fdrefresh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliSt_config WHERE name = 'feedMemory".$_GET['fd_refresh']."'");
$refresh = mysql_fetch_assoc($fdrefresh);

$pieces = explode("-:-", $refresh['value']);

$fdURLfeed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliSt_config WHERE name = 'csvURL".$_GET['fd_refresh']."'");
$URLfeed = mysql_fetch_assoc($fdURLfeed);
$fdtypeFeed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliSt_config WHERE name = 'csvType".$_GET['fd_refresh']."'");
$typeFeed = mysql_fetch_assoc($fdtypeFeed);

    if ($typeFeed['value'] == 'tab') {
    $typeFeed = "\t";
    } else {
    $typeFeed = $typeFeed['value'];
    }

// set row variable and open file
$row = intval($pieces[11]);
if ($URLfeed['title'] == 'Upload Feed') {
$handle = fopen('../'.$URLfeed['value'], "r");
} else {
$handle = fopen($URLfeed['value'], "r");
}
// empty the table
$empty = "DELETE FROM affiliSt_products WHERE prodDB IN ('".$_GET['fd_refresh']."')";
mysql_query($empty);

// start auto inc from last ID in db
$autoinc = mysql_query("SELECT prodID FROM affiliSt_products ORDER BY prodDB DESC LIMIT 1");
$autoincnum = mysql_fetch_assoc($autoinc);
$resetautoinc = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE affiliSt_products AUTO_INCREMENT = ".($autoincnum['prodID']+1)."");

// while loop with fgetcsv sorts the csv into the data array 
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 6000, $typeFeed)) !== FALSE) {

    $resulta = $pieces[0];
    if ($data[intval($pieces[1])] == NULL) {
    $resultb = $row;
    } else {
    $resultb = $data[intval($pieces[1])];
    }
    switch ($feedOpts[0]) {
        case 0:
            $resultc = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[2])]));
            $resultd = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[3])]));
            $resulte = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[4])]));
            break;
        case 1:
            $resultc = $data[intval($pieces[2])];
            $resultd = $data[intval($pieces[3])];
            $resulte = $data[intval($pieces[4])];
            break;
        case 2:
            if (isset($feedOpts[1]) && $feedOpts[1] == 1) {
                $resultc = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[2])]));
            } else {
                $resultc = $data[intval($pieces[2])];
            }
            if (isset($feedOpts[2]) && $feedOpts[2] == 1) {
                $resultd = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[3])]));
            } else {
                $resultd = $data[intval($pieces[3])];
            }
            if (isset($feedOpts[3]) && $feedOpts[3] == 1) {
                $resulte = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[4])]));
            } else {
                $resulte = $data[intval($pieces[4])];
            }
            break;
        default: //catchall
            $resultc = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[2])]));
            $resultd = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[3])]));
            $resulte = ucwords(strtolower($data[intval($pieces[4])]));
            break;
    }
    $resultf = $data[intval($pieces[5])];
    $resultg = $data[intval($pieces[6])];
    $resulth = $data[intval($pieces[7])];
    $resulti = $data[intval($pieces[8])];
    $resultj = $data[intval($pieces[9])];
    $resultk = $pieces[10];
    $resultm = $data[intval($pieces[14])];
    $resultn = $data[intval($pieces[15])];
    $resulto = $data[intval($pieces[16])];
    $resultp = $data[intval($pieces[17])];
    $resultq = $data[intval($pieces[18])];
    $resultr = $data[intval($pieces[34])];
    $results = intval($row);

    if ($pieces[12] == 'before') {
    $resulth = $pieces[13].$resulth;
    } else if ($pieces[12] == 'after') {
    $resulth = $resulth.$pieces[13];
    }

// remove characters that may interfear with navigation or display
    include("../../includes/fixlist.inc.php");

    $resultc = str_replace($andAmps, "and", $resultc);
    $resultd = str_replace($andAmps, "and", $resultd);
    $resulte = str_replace($andAmps, "and", $resulte);
    $resultc = str_replace($charquotes, "", $resultc);
    $resultd = str_replace($charquotes, "", $resultd);
    $resulte = str_replace($charquotes, "", $resulte);
    $resultb = str_replace($allCharacters, "-", $resultb);
    $resultc = str_replace($allCharacters, " ", $resultc);
    $resultd = str_replace($someCharacters, " ", $resultd);
    $resulte = str_replace($allCharacters, " ", $resulte);
    $resultj = str_replace($currencyCharacters, " ", $resultj);
    $resultl = $_GET['fd_refresh'];

// miss out headers row
   if ($row != 0) {
   // insert all the data into the database table
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO affiliSt_products (

                merchant,   
                merchantProdID,     
                prodCategory,   
                prodName,   
                prodBrand,  
                prodDescription,    
                prodPromoText,  
                prodLink,   
                prodImageURL,   
                prodPrice, 
                prodCurrency,
                prodDB,
                extraFieldA,
                extraFieldB,
                extraFieldC,
                extraFieldD,
                extraFieldE,    
                prodImageSmall,     
                dbProdID

                ) VALUES (

                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s
                )",
                quote_smart($resulta),
                quote_smart($resultb),
                quote_smart($resultc),
                quote_smart($resultd),
                quote_smart($resulte),
                quote_smart($resultf),
                quote_smart($resultg),
                quote_smart($resulth),
                quote_smart($resulti),
                quote_smart($resultj),
                quote_smart($resultk),
                quote_smart($resultl),
                quote_smart($resultm),
                quote_smart($resultn),
                quote_smart($resulto),
                quote_smart($resultp),
                quote_smart($resultq),
                quote_smart($resultr),
                quote_smart($results));
        mysql_query($sql, $databaseConnect) or die(mysql_error());
        }

    $row++;
    }

// create the new config nav
// category listing
$getCategory = mysql_query("SELECT prodCategory FROM affiliSt_products WHERE prodDB = '".$_GET['fd_refresh']."' ORDER BY prodCategory ASC");
$categoryList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCategory);
$newnavigation = '';
do { 
    if ($feedOpts[0] == 0 || ($feedOpts[0] == 2 && $feedOpts[1] == 1)) {
        $catresult = ucwords(strtolower($categoryList['prodCategory']));
    } else {
        $catresult = $categoryList['prodCategory'];
    }
    if ($storedCategory != $catresult && $catresult != NULL) {
        $newnavigation .= $catresult;
        // start sub nav
        // brand listing
        $getBrands = mysql_query("SELECT prodBrand FROM affiliSt_products WHERE prodDB = '".$_GET['fd_refresh']."' AND prodCategory = '$catresult' ORDER BY prodBrand ASC");
        $brandList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getBrands);
        do {
            if ($feedOpts[0] == 0 || ($feedOpts[0] == 2 && $feedOpts[3] == 1)) {
                $theresult = ucwords(strtolower($brandList['prodBrand']));
            } else {
                $theresult = $brandList['prodBrand'];
            }
            if ($storedBrand != $theresult && $theresult != NULL) {
                $newnavigation .= '(:)'.$theresult;
                $storedBrand = $theresult;
                $brandrow++;
            } else {
                if ($feedOpts[0] == 0 || ($feedOpts[0] == 2 && $feedOpts[3] == 1)) {
                    $theresult = ucwords(strtolower($brandList['prodBrand']));
                } else {
                    $theresult = $brandList['prodBrand'];
                }               
            }
        } while ($brandList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getBrands));
        $storedCategory = $catresult;
        $newnavigation .= '-:-';
    } else {
        if ($feedOpts[0] == 0 || ($feedOpts[0] == 2 && $feedOpts[1] == 1)) {
            $catresult = ucwords(strtolower($categoryList['prodCategory']));
        } else {
            $catresult = $categoryList['prodCategory'];
        }   
    }
} while ($categoryList = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCategory));
$newnavigation = rtrim($newnavigation, '-:-');

$sql= "DELETE FROM affiliSt_config WHERE name='nav".$_GET['fd_refresh']."'" ;        
mysql_query($sql, $databaseConnect) or die(mysql_error());
$insert = array (
        array ( 'name' =>  'nav'.$_GET['fd_refresh'],
                'value' => $newnavigation,
                'comment' => 'Category and subcategory navigation',
                'title' => 'Generated Navigation')
);

// insert values posted from Step 1 into config table
foreach ($insert as $row) {
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO affiliSt_config (
            name, value, comment, title
            ) values (
            %s, %s, %s, %s
            )",
            quote_smart($row['name']),
            quote_smart($row['value']),
            quote_smart($row['comment']),
            quote_smart($row['title']));
    mysql_query($sql, $databaseConnect) or die(mysql_error());
}
// end config nav



// get config details
$getMyEmail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliSt_config WHERE name = 'adEmail'");
$myEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($getMyEmail);

// new link email
$myemailaddress = $myEmail['value'];
$emailaddress = $myemailaddress;
$subject = $pieces[0]." Cron Just Updated";
$emailmessage = $emailNew['value'];
$emailfrom = $myemailaddress;
$messageb .= "Dear Admin\n\n".$pieces[0]." cron just updated"."\n\n";
$runtime = (date("d M Y H:i"));
$messageb .= "Time of the message: $runtime (server time zone)\n\n";
mail($emailaddress, $subject, $messageb, "From: $emailfrom");

}
?>
```

Comment: please consider posting the script at fault, it is very much mandatory for us to help you :)

Comment: is there another .htaccess that may be overwriting the original value?

Comment: Are you sure it's running and not crashing with an undisplayed error? Check your logs!

Comment: Thanks for all your reply's; there is no other .htaccess overruling the main one (to be sure i copied the main one to the target folder). The script is not crashing; when finished it should send an e-mail and that is still does. So it looks like the max execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with a curl script. I tried the ini set and set_time_limit but it still did not work for more than 3-10 minutes. So after I runned it from a terminal it wordked like a charm. If you can you can exsecute it as a terminal command or via a cron job like :

```
php path-to-file/file.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; just added it to my cron twice; one with the php command and one without, now we wait to see if it works.

Comment: Cron also does not work (most likely because the parameter are not passing trough the script.

Answer (score 0):

I havnt experienced like this before..After refeering some link i have found a solution..

Use php in `safe mode`  and try the code below

```
if( !ini_get('safe_mode') ){ 
set_time_limit(0); //this won't work if safe_mode is enabled.
}
```

Found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284731/php-cannot-change-max-execution-time-in-xampp).

Comment: Php in safe mode does not allow the time limit to be changed? But i tried the code and it doesn't work...